# regular expression for phone valid at class

Tags: php, regex, class

i have to make valid for mobile phone with this expression

```
00-972-598-195-871
```

i make this function

```
    private function phoneVald($phone) {
    return ereg("/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/",$phone);
}
```

and this is the condition for the expression

```
public function setPhone($phone) {

    if ($this-> phoneVald($phone)) {
        $this-> phone = $phone;
    } else {
        echo "<br />Bad Phone Number";
    }
}
```

when i call it

```
$mine = new frindContInfo(00-972-598-195-871);
```

i got Bad Phone Number

is there any problem with my code !?

Comment: i think ereg is depreciated. You could use preg_match.

Comment: i did and it's work but when i use it inside class not work

$phone = '00-972-598-195-871';

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/", $phone)) {
  echo " good phone";
}
else{
    echo "bad phone";
}

Comment: then the problem is not with the regex. There is something with your code.

Comment: as u can see i put the function and if condition for the function ,, the class work well , but the function inside class not work

Answer (score 0):

Your `regex` is right , try this way to call your `method` from `friendContInfo` class. you can use also `__construct()` to set your `$phone` on object instantiation.

see here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

```
    class frindContInfo {

    public function setPhone($phone){
      if ($this-> phoneVald($phone)) {
         $this-> phone = $phone;
         } else {
         echo "<br />Bad Phone Number";
         }
      }

    private function phoneVald($phone) 
     {
      return ereg("/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9] 
      {3}$/",$phone);
     }
 }

$object = new frindContInfo();

$object->setPhone('00-972-598-195-871');
```

Comment: i did this .. 

    function __construct($fname, $lname, $phone, $email) {

        $this->setFname($fname);
        $this->setLname($lname);
        $this->setEmail($email);
        $this->setPhone($phone);
    }

the same problem